# Is it possible to manually traverse nested if statements?

Tags: objective-c, c, if-statement

Binary trees are confusing me into inactivity, so I thought I'd try a simpler (if significantly messier) approach.
For example...

```
if (a) {
    do something
    // wait for a button press before checking the next 'if'
    if (aa) {
        do something
    } else if (ab) {
        do something
    }
} else if (b) {
    do something else
}
```

Et cetera.
How do I force my app to wait for a button press before asking if 'aa' returns true? (And so on and so forth.)

Switches seem like a cleaner alternative, so if someone has an answer for that method instead, I'd be happy to give it a go. It's the same problem, though. I can't figure out how to progress step by step rather than all at once.

Comment: retagged as this isnt anything to do with objective-c , its a straight c query

Comment: My apologies. The only C-related thing I've done that isn't Objective-C was a peek at C++ in a Box2D (Cocos2D physics engine) tutorial. Not quite the same, but you get the point.

Comment: Wouldn't a debugger do what you want? Or is there more to this than merely examining the runtime behavior of your code?

Comment: I guess it would have been helpful to say so from the beginning, but it didn't seem important at the time. Silly me. I'm hoping for something that will, for example, allow a player to have multiple options for interactions with an NPC. Think Dragon Age or Mass Effect 2, but on a much smaller scale.

Comment: I'll try to answer your Q about ME2/DA in my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach, using a state or control variable for the view, to determine what it should do next given the button presses.

```
// pseudo-code based on your example
-(IBAction) buttonPress1
if (a) {
    do something
    self.setState = stateA;
} else if (b) {
    do something else
    self.setState = stateB;
}

-(IBAction) buttonPress2
 if (self.state == stateA) {
    if (a) {
        do something
    } else if (b) {
        do something
    }
 }
```

hope that helps, if not, ask away in the comments.

---

[EDIT]

OK, after you explained the DA/ME/ME2 reference I get what you're looking for.

What you're maybe going to want to do, is store your Dialogue in a plist, to load into a NSDictionary. (read up on NSDictionary)

Each NSDictionary should look like this:

key = value

@"prompt" = @"hi my name is bob"
@"MEAN" = NSDictionary object for next convo choice for mean
@"NICE" = NSDictionary object for next convo choice for nice

```
const BOOL NICE = YES;
const BOOL MEAN = !NICE;

NSDictionary *convo = //loaded to initial starting point from your plist file

- (IBAction) playerChoseMean:(id)sender
{
    [self sayConvo:convo withChoice:MEAN];
}

- (IBAction) playerChoseNice:(id)sender
{
    [self sayConvo:convo withChoice:NICE];
}

- (void) sayConvo:(NSDictionary)convo withChoice:(BOOL)b
{
  NSLog(@"NPC says: %@", [convo valueForKey:@"prompt"]);
  if(b) {
     convo = (NSDictionary*)[convo valueForKey:@"NICE"];
  } else {
     convo = (NSDictionary*)[convo valueForKey:@"MEAN"];
  }

  if (convo == [NSNull null] || convo == nil) then continue;
  //else continue
}
```

Here's an example NSDictionary graph which should get you started.

```
NSDictionary *intro = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
NSDictionary *nice = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
NSDictionary *nicenice = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
NSDictionary *nicegoodbye = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
NSDictionary *mean = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];
NSDictionary *meangoodbye = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:3];

[intro addValue:@"hi there!" forKey:prompt];
[intro addValue:nice forKey:@"NICE"];
[intro addValue:mean forKey:@"MEAN"];

[nice addValue:@"that was nice" forKey:prompt];
[nice addValue:nicenice forKey:@"NICE"];
[nice addValue:mean forKey:@"MEAN"];

[nicenice addValue:@"awww" forKey:prompt];
[nicenice addValue:nicegoodbye forKey:@"NICE"];
[nicenice addValue:mean forKey:@"MEAN"];

[nicegoodbye addValue:@"you were super nice, here's a bonus for being so nice" forKey:prompt];
[nicegoodbye addValue:[NSNull null] forKey:@"NICE"];
[nicegoodbye addValue:[NSNull null] forKey:@"MEAN"];

[mean addValue:@"that was mean" forKey:prompt];
[mean addValue:nice forKey:@"NICE"];
[mean addValue:meangoodbye forKey:@"MEAN"];

[meangoodbye addValue:@"you're a jerk!  goodbye!" forKey:prompt];
[meangoodbye addValue:[NSNull null] forKey:@"NICE"];
[meangoodbye addValue:[NSNull null] forKey:@"MEAN"];
```

---

Take a look at this excellent example over on [GameDeve.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31/how-can-i-implement-dialog-trees-into-my-game)

Comment: I meant that each if-else is managed by buttons. Button 1 returns true on the initial condition (if), Button 2 returns true on the other one (else if). If that makes any sense. Your bit of code there is useful somewhere, I'm sure, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Thromordyn, I posted some additional stuff.

Comment: You'll have to ask a more database-minded person, as I'm sure this is even easier to implement in CoreData.

Comment: I think I understand what you're doing here… Yes, yes, that looks excellent. So it's a dictionary of dictionaries to handle each possible conversation, yes? I think I have a (dead) app with some code to help me with grabbing information from a plist… I'm still getting hung up on exactly how to step through the conversation. I'll take a look at SE. (I've only looked at CoreData once, and it looks like a lot to learn. Is it worth it (like sqlite3) or should I stick with what I already (mostly) know?)

Comment: Ray Wenderlich has some great tutorials. I'll see what I can do with CoreData.

Comment: @Thromordyn, did you see the link at the very bottom of my post?

Comment: The "GameDeve.SE" thing? Yeah. It was confusing me, but CoreData is even harder to get, so I'll go back to that. Today just isn't a great day for learning new things…

Comment: @Thromordyn, glad to help.  I'll eventually need to do this for my apps.

Answer (score 1):

If the present function is in secondary thread then you can use

CFRunLoopRun() -- stop the thread then once button is pressed call CFRunLoopStop() to resume the operation.

**I would prefer you to do same implementation bit differently:**
Brake the flow in to 2 parts

in first part ---

```
if (a) {
    do something

    }
} else if (b) {
    do something else
}
```

in second part do --- do this once button is clicked.

```
   if (aa) {
        do something
    } else if (ab) {
        do something
```

Comment: Brake is slow/stop. Break is destroy/separate. Just so you know. … Uh... Multi-threading? I've never had any need for that, but it looks pretty convenient. … What exactly do you mean by "parts"? Multiple methods, or completely separate loops that are used as necessary? I was hoping to keep everything as compact as possible.

Comment: part I mean -- they should be placed in different functions.

Comment: If you give some more detail I may be able to help you better.